# fetch data filtering value of object's key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is my document structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c51b3e2bb564f3f1ccf84c2"),
    "createdAt" : 1548858338324,
    "updatedAt" : 1548858843028,
    "teamId" : "ef08f13",
    "analytics" : {
        "aggregate" : {
            "averageViewTime" : 5.6000000000000005,
            "averageClicks" : 2.5,
            "totalViews" : 2,
            "totalVisits" : 4
        },
        "days" : {
            "28-12-2018" : {
                "dayAvgViewTime" : 5.6000000000000005,
                "dayAvgClicks" : 2.5,
                "dayViews" : 2,
                "dayVisits" : 4
            },
            "20-01-2019" : {
                "dayAvgViewTime" : 5.6000000000000005,
                "dayAvgClicks" : 2.5,
                "dayViews" : 2,
                "dayVisits" : 4
            },

        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the record if `analytics.days` object's key match in a given range. for example, if I want a record in between begin-date `"15-01-2019"` and end date `"25-01-2019"`.  it should return this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c51b3e2bb564f3f1ccf84c2"),
    "createdAt" : 1548858338324,
    "updatedAt" : 1548858843028,
    "teamId" : "ef08f13",
    "analytics" : {
        "aggregate" : {
            "averageViewTime" : 5.6000000000000005,
            "averageClicks" : 2.5,
            "totalViews" : 2,
            "totalVisits" : 4
        },
        "days" : {
            "20-01-2019" : {
                "dayAvgViewTime" : 5.6000000000000005,
                "dayAvgClicks" : 2.5,
                "dayViews" : 2,
                "dayVisits" : 4
            },

        }
    }
}
```